# The effective (time integrated) Hamiltonian in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, scattering, time-evolution

In the Heisenberg picture of quantum mechanics, the states are time independent, while the operators are. The time evolution of (not explicitly time dependent) operators $A(t)$ is then given by the Heisenberg equation:

$$ i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}A(t)=[A(t),H(t)] \tag{1}\label{1} $$

where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes the commutator and $H(t)$ is the (time dependent) Hamiltonian.

Transforming between the pictures of quantum mechanics usually employs the time evolution operator:

$$ U(t,t_0)=\mathcal{T}\mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^t dt' H(t')\right) \tag{2} $$

where $\mathcal{T}$ is the time ordering symbol.

Another important concept is the scattering operator which may be defined as

$$ S = \lim_{t_0\rightarrow-\infty\\t\rightarrow+\infty}U(t,t_0) \tag{3}$$

and might be written as

$$ S := -\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt H(t) \tag{4}\label{4}$$

as a *first order approximation*, where an identity operator has been omitted.

My question is now regarding mixing these two pictures. In my lecture notes I found that we did the following:

1. We set up a time dependent Hamiltonian describing some system.
2. We integrated the Hamiltonian similar to equation (\ref{4}). We called the result the "effective" Hamiltonian. This was explaint as some long interaction taking place. The resulting Hamiltonian should be the Hamiltonian after this interaction, if I understand it correctly.
3. We calculated the time evolution of some operators as if we were in the Heisenberg picture by using (\ref{1}). Thus, overall we calculated

$$ i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}A(t)=[A(t),S] \tag{5}  $$

I am a bit confused by this as it is not directly clear to me, which picture we are working in here. Is there a more formal way to justify the time integration of step 2?

Comment: "In the Schrödinger picture of quantum mechanics, the states are time independent, while the operators are." -- You mean the Heisenberg picture, right?

Comment: @DvijD.C. Ah yes, I fixed that.

Comment: Thanks :) Also, are you sure that your $(5)$ is correct? $i\hbar d_t A(t) = [A(t),H(t)]$ is what I would expect. Or, after integration, I would expect, $S^\dagger A(t\to - \infty)S = A(t\to\infty)$, where I am using the notation that does not omit the identity operator.

Comment: @DvijD.C. That's what I'm trying to figure out...

Comment: I might be missing something but prima facie, it looks fishy. Can you link to a reference for more context?

Comment: Silly question, I'm sure, but what does $t'$ stand for?

Comment: @Gert That's just to ensure that the upper integral boundary is not the same as the integration variable.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks.